# count tools in page

Tags: c#, image-viewer

I have used a scroll viewer in my WP App C# and some image viewers.
For setting my scroll viewer height i want to use a dynamic code.
so in class i have code :

```
private void load(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    int a ;
    a=60;
    Scr.Height=
}
```

i want something that can count my imageviewers that are recognized in Xml 
for example i have 10 image viewers and their height is 60.
i want something like this :

```
private void load(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    int a;
    a=60;
    Scr.Height=10*a
}
```

---

Thanks

Comment: If you put controls into some container, then you can use this container `Height` to get combined height of its children.

Comment: @Sinatr would you explain more or just give me source to read?

Comment: Is it wpf? Then start from [here](http://www.wpftutorial.net/LayoutProperties.html).

Comment: @Sinatr not Wpf - Windowsphone app C# - Silverlight